# How to use OPENGL API in wince 6.0 r3 platform builder

Tags: c++, opengl-es, windows-ce, platform-builder, silverlight-embedded

How to use the following interface in wince 6.0 r3 for implementing hardware acceleration for graphics in silverlight

1. IRenderer
2. ICustomSurface
3. ICustomGraphicsDevice

Comment: You can try and get OMAP3530's bsp. I know it includes HW acceleration for Silverlight, but I am not sure the source for the acceleration is available. As far as I know it only requires registration to get the bsp. http://software-dl.ti.com/dsps/dsps_public_sw/sdo_sb/targetcontent/bsp/latest/index_FDS.html

Comment: @Shaihi: I have OMAP3530 bsp. I have went through demo example provided with the OMAP3530 bsp. The API which they use are different then the API used in IMX515 for OpenGL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find here a Guide how to implement the Hardware acceleration for Silverlight in WEC7.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj919286.aspx

(I recommend to use Windows Embedded 7 for Silverlight if possible, Microsoft did quite some improvements compared to wince 6.0 r3)

Alternative you can also use a module which proivdes the HW acceleration out of the box.
Here a video which shows the differenc with enable/disable HW acceleration:
http://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/microsoft-silverlight

If you mainly want to have a fancy 3D User interface, take also a look at the Nvidia UI Composer which is available for Win CE 6 too.